# Why does the 'input' event not get fired when changing the value of an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, event-listener

Consider a minimal form such as the following:

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let firstNameInput = document.querySelector("#firstName");

firstNameInput.style.borderColor = "red";

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  firstNameInput.value = "Goofy";
});

firstNameInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  firstNameInput.style.borderColor = "black";
})
```

```css
.form__input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="firstName">Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form__input" id="firstName">

  <button type="button">Button</button>
</form>
```

When loading this page, you should see an input field with a red bottom-border and next to it a button. If you click on the button, the name "Goofy" is written inside the input field. However, the bottom-border stays red. I would like it to change its color whenever something is written inside the input field. Now, when I go on and change the name manually, the border-color changes its color to black, just as I want. But can anyone explain to me why the border-color did not change when clicking on the button?

Comment: The `input` event is not fired when the contents are changed programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input event is an [UI-Event](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#interface-inputevent), it's meant to fire when the user does action the page, not when scripts do.
For your case your script can simply call the same callback when it does set the `.value`.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let firstNameInput = document.querySelector("#firstName");
const setBorderColor = () => {
  firstNameInput.style.borderColor = "black";
};
firstNameInput.style.borderColor = "red";

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  firstNameInput.value = "Goofy";
  setBorderColor();
});

firstNameInput.addEventListener('input', setBorderColor)
```

```css
.form__input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="firstName">Firstname:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form__input" id="firstName">

  <button type="button">Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thx a lot Kaiido!